# Store output of loop into string and return in method

Tags: c#

I have a method that draws a triangle using a loop that prints to the console each line. I require to change the modifiers to `public static string` instead of `public static void` so I require a return type of string. How could I manipulate my code so that the method returns a multi-lined string of the drawn shape?

Comment: Can you return `string[]`? If so I can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Investigate [`System.Text.StringBuilder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx). Create one at the start of your method, then instead of `Console.Write` call `yourStringBuilderInstance.Append()`. At the end of your method, `return yourStringBuilderInstance.ToString()`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'm receiving: there is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'length' from the `stringBuilder.ToString(" ");`

Comment: I said `yourStringBuilderInstance.ToString()` not `.ToString(" ")`. If you get an error you have to add your code to your question.

Comment: You should use a descriptive name like `triangle`, not `stringBuilder`, and `.AppendLine()` instead of `WriteLine()`. And throw an [`ArgumentException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sxykka64(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of an error message so your caller will know it got an error instead of a triangle.

Comment: Understood. It's currently printing one big singular line as opposed to the shape. I suppose the string should be in some sort of multi-lined format?

Comment: I don't know what “singular lines” are; you have to post what you have to your question because I can't see your screen. Your question still has `.Append()` where I told you to use `.AppendLine()`.

Comment: Oh my bad sorry. It displays correctly now if I call it using `Console.Write(DrawIsoscelesTriangle(5));` however `DrawIsoscelesTriangle(5);` does not print anything.

Comment: Of course `DrawIsoscelesTriangle(5)` does not print anything; you changed it to return a string instead of outputting to the console (except if it gets an error, where you should **not** be writing to the console). If you wrote `string s = "Hello;"` would you expect that to write to the console? No, you would have to use `Console.WriteLine(s)`.